JobRunr: Disable NoSQL Storage Configuration
I am using the jobrunr-spring-boot-3-starter, version 7.0.0-RC.1, and have a PostgreSQL database set up - which is picked up as the default storage provider by JobRunr.
Now, I have added a Redis integration (via Lettuce), and JobRunr has started picking it up as the default storage, which I don't want.
I haven't applied any custom configuration to JobRunr. What is the best approach to force JobRunr to stick with the PostgreSQL datasource?

You can configure JobRunr to use your SQL database by means of the following spring boot property:
org.jobrunr.database.type=sql


By the way: JobRunr v7.0.0 is out, so no need for the RC.1!
